# Aws- Dynamodb ,Getting ClientError while updating items in Dynamodb

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, amazon-dynamodb

i have to update multiple items in the dynamodb based on number of keys available in a list. I am trying to update with below approach. i use boto3 and instantiated the dynamodb which it works as expected for other action.

```
id_list=['id1','id2','id3']
ddb_table = mydb
dttm=mytimestamp
flg="Y"
pk='123'

response=''
if id_list  is not None:
   for id in id_list:
       response=ddb_table.update_item(
            Key={
                'pk':pk,
                'id':id 
                },
            UpdateExpression="SET var1InTable= :dttm, var2InTable= :flg",
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':dttm': dttm,
                ':flg': flg
                },
            )
        print("response",response)
        return response
```

But i am getting below error:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema
```

#Expected:
for the same pk, number of id will be created and it would updated as separate entry in the DynamoDB which is expected in our case and its working fine,
now i need to set deltime and flag for all those id listed in the id list.

i am not sure what would be issue here?
Appreciated if anybody can help on this?

Thanks

Comment: Are `pk` and `id` the actual names for the partition and sort keys?

Comment: HI @JonSG pk is the partition key and id is one of the column name  and not a sort keys.

Comment: You have to pass in the partition and sort key to update_item(). Since `id` is not the actual sort key, you will want to run a query/scan in order to find the actual partition and sort keys of the items in question and then run the update with them.